# Client does not receive UDP datagram from server if the server responds from a different port

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp, nat

### Environment:

**Client** - Windows desktop behind NAT, runs a UDP client application.

**Server** - Ubuntu server with public IP, runs a UDP server application that expects packets on port 6000.

**ClientPrivate/Public** - private/public IPs of the client

**ServerPrivate/Public** - private/public IPs of the server

---

### Case 1:

1. Client opens a UDP socket on ***ClientPrivate:777*** and sends a datagram to ***ServerPublic:6000***
2. Server receives the datagram from ***ClientPublic:777*** and sends a response to ***ClientPublic:777*** from ***ServerPrivate:6000***
3. Client receives the response and everything is fine

**WireShark output on Server:**

`475  88.xxx.xxx.90 -> 10.0.0.5       UDP 777 → 6000
476  10.0.0.5      -> 88.xxx.xxx.90  UDP 6000 → 777`

**WireShark output on Client:**

`152 192.168.2.85    104.40.xxx.250  UDP 777 → 6000 
153 104.40.xxx.250  192.168.2.85    UDP 6000 → 777`

---

### Case 2:

1. Client opens a UDP socket on ***ClientPrivate:777*** and sends a datagram to ***ServerPublic:6000***
2. Server receives the datagram from ***ClientPublic:777***
3. Server opens a new socket on ***ServerPrivate:46666*** and sends a datagram to ***ClientPublic:777***
4. Client **does not** receive the datagram

**WireShark output on Server:**

`475  88.xxx.xxx.90 -> 10.0.0.5       UDP 777 → 6000
476  10.0.0.5      -> 88.xxx.xxx.90  UDP 46666 → 777`

**WireShark output on Client:**

`152 192.168.2.85    104.40.xxx.250  UDP 777 → 6000`

---

### Question:

Why **does** the Client receive a datagram in Case 1 and **does not** in Case 2?

Comment: Is the `ServerPrivate` network connected to the `ClientPublic` network in any way? If not, then how would you expect the packet to be able to be sent between the two networks? Don't the `sendto` call fail in the server?

Comment: Nothing fails. Client just does not receive the datagram. The networks are not connected (only over the internet). How do I expect..? I do not know.. that's why I described the tho cases. If it would not work in both cases I would not ask, but it does work in the first case.

Comment: For a packet to be able to go from one host to another, there needs to be some connection (however indirect) between the networks of the host. If there is no such connection, or there is no routing telling where packets should be sent, then it's simply not possible. If the servers private network is indeed private, and there is no physical connection to the clients public network (however indirect) then packets can't be transferred. How would it pass through a non-existing connection? In the first case the two public networks are clearly connected, that's why it works.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable but I still don't get it. Why are the networks clearly connected in the first case and are not connected in the second case?

Comment: The real question here is why is the server responding from a different port? Don't waste ports. Use the same socket to respond that the request was received with.

Comment: @EJP This is a quite old third-party application running on the server which is just built that way to respond from a different port. What you are saying is a good piece of advice but is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the client-side NAT. When your client sends to the server public IP, the NAT router is making an entry in its internal table of connections (something like "192.168.2.85[777] => 104.40.xxx.250[6000]).

So when a response comes back from 104.40.xxx.250[6000] the NAT will find the matching entry and return the response to the client machine. That entry is how it knows which machine in the client network to send the packet to. However, when a response comes back from 104.40.xx.250[46666], that doesn't match any entry in its table so it's dropping that packet.

This is the way NAT works. Consider if you had another machine behind your NAT *also* talking to the same server, say, "192.168.2.*86*[777] => 104.40.xxx.250[6000]". I think you would find your NAT router actually changing the source port to something other than 777. Else how can it properly route the response back to the correct machine. In general for NAT, if the incoming packet from the router doesn't match an entry in its table (*OR* you've configured a port-forwarding rule) the packet will be dropped.

Port-forwarding allows you to open up your internal machine for general access by the outside world. But lacking that, you really don't want any random IP address / port pair to be able to send a datagram to your client machine.

Comment: The problem is in fact caused by NAT. It is required to first send a packet from a client to server, so that NAT can create a proper mapping entry to route response packet(s) back to the client. If there were no outgoing packets from the client to the server and the server just sends packets to the client, they will be discarded since there is no proper mapping yet on the NAT box.